# Column Name Convention

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I want to specify a column name convention that basically takes a pascal cased field and converts it to all uppercase with underscores.  So property OrderId becomes column "ORDER_ID". I also want this convention to be applied only if I don't already specify one in the mapping.  So far I have the skeleton below:

```
public class PascalCaseColumnNameConvention : IPropertyConvention
{
    public bool Accept(IPropertyInstance instance)
    {
        //Not sure what I should have here
    }
    public void Apply(IPropertyInstance instance)
    {
        instance.Column(instance.Property.Name.ChangePascalCaseToUnderscore());
    }
}
```

Also is there a better way of channging the case besides an string extension method?  Any libraries that already do this sort of thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Accept` method in this case you should just `return true`. This method is to decide whether your convention should apply for a given instance, for example you might want to change the default name only for your `int`-typed fields etc. If you're defining a general convention, `true` means just "accept all instances". <strike>It can be still overriden by specyfying the column name in the mapping, though.</strike>

About changing the case - I don't know such a library, either. But the task is quite simple, so your solution seems very reasonable here.

**EDIT**

Well, what FNH version are you using? I can't see `IPropertyConvention` to have `bool Accept` method.

What you can do here is to implement both `IPropertyConvention` (with `void Apply` only) and `IPropertyConventionAcceptance` (with `Accept` method working a bit differently). Try something like that (haven't tested):

```
public class PascalCaseColumnNameConvention : IPropertyConvention, IPropertyConventionAcceptance
{
    public void Accept(IAcceptanceCriteria<IPropertyInspector> criteria)
    {
        criteria.Expect(x => !x.Columns.HasUserDefined());
    }

    public void Apply(IPropertyInstance instance)
    {
        instance.Column(instance.Property.Name.ChangePascalCaseToUnderscore());
    }
}
```

I've also found a neat class doing lot of useful string conversions - see [Inflector](https://github.com/srkirkland/Inflector/blob/master/Inflector/Inflector.cs). But anyway, if you need only this particular conversion, I would stay with own simple solution.

Comment: I ran some tests and it does not seem to "ignore" the convention if I have already specified a column name.  It still tries to apply the convention.  I wrote some additional handling inside my string extension method to detect this but just thought I'd let you know.

Comment: @Cole W - you're right, user-defined convensions are more important than overrides, quite strange for me. Anyway, I've tried another solution - see edit.